# A problem with the usage of recursive XML schema types

Tags: xml, recursion, xsd

It is easy to define two elements with the same name like `<any>` in one XML schema and different permitted subelements. One should just declare two XSD types `AnyType1` and `AnyType2` as `complexTypes` which describes permitted subelements. Then one can declare element `<any>` in one context as `<xs:element name="any" type="AnyType1" />` and as `<xs:element name="any" type="AnyType2" />` in another context. My problem is that both `AnyType1` and `AnyType2` are recursive. To define a recursive type in XSD I use the following syntax

```
<xs:element name="any" type="AnyType1" />
<xs:complexType name="AnyType1">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <!-- … some permitted subelements -->
        <xs:element name="any" type="AnyType1" />
        <!-- … some other permitted subelements -->
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Disadvantage of this syntax is that we have to declare the element `"any"` **on the top of schema** and we can’t use `<xs:element name="any" type="AnyType2" />` later to define recursive type `AnyType2` somewhere later.

**My question is: how to declare two recursive element types in the same XML schema in the same namespace.**

The background of my question is following. I need to define XML schema which describe some tests. The tests should be combined (grouped) with respect of `<all>` and `<any>` elements ("or" and "and" operations) to describes results of some tests. In one context (in one place of XML file) I need to allow one subset of tests which can be grouped by `<all>` and `<any>` and in another place other subelements should be permitted. So I don’t want to define `<anyTest1>` and `<anyTest2>` elements or `<n1:any>` and `<n2:any>`. I want just use `<any>`, but if `<any>` is subelement of `<TestBeforeProgramStart>` I want allow one subset of subelements and if `<any>` is subelement of `<TestAfterProgramEnd>` another subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on my question myself. It seems very simple.

It is not need to declare `<xs:element name="any" type="AnyType1" />` before `<xs:complexType name="AnyType1">`, so the declaration of the type `AnyType1` can be just following

```
<xs:complexType name="AnyType1">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <!-- … some permitted subelements -->
        <xs:element name="any" type="AnyType1" />
        <!-- … some other permitted subelements -->
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

So the problem which I described seems not really exist.